# How to open facebook messenger chat window using app-scoped id in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I can get a app-scoped user id with graph-api in my application.
Then, how to open facebook messenger chat window using app-scoped id in android.

We can open facebook messenger chat window using global-facebook-id(using intent and uri).

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/");
uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, Long.parseLong(peopleId));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

But, it is not possible to get global-facebook-id using app-scoped-id.

Then, I want to know how to open facebook messenger chat window using app-scoped-id only. I don't need to send a private message just opening is all I need.

Thank you for your reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.
The only way developers can interface with Facebook Messenger is to...

- build a page management app that can [respond to messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/conversations) that individual people have sent to a page, or...
- build a [messenger platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger) app.